# Python 3.8 - Can't install python-telegram-bot package

Tags: python, python-3.x

That's what I'm getting:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dtsq0g9n\cffi\
Command "C:\Users\Mark\PycharmProjects\testbook\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Mark\PycharmProjects\testbook\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u3iqfwfs\overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools>=40.6.0 wheel "cffi>=1.8,!=1.11.3;
platform_python_implementation != 'PyPy'"" failed with error code 1 in None
```

I'm very new to python and programming as a whole so forgive me if this is a dumb question

Comment: You didn't include the part of the output that contains the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

`python-telegram-bot` does not support python 3.8 yet.

Here's how you can see that on their [releases page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/releases) on GitHub. This is the commits that have been pushed to `master` since last release: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/compare/v12.4.2...master Notice that the support for python 3.8 has not been released yet.

If you can, downgrade to Python 3.7 and proceed as normal.